# How can I allow ap-hotspot in ufw Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: wireless, firewall, iptables, ufw, hot-spot

When ufw is enable android stuck in `obtaining ip address` and cannot connect to wifi. I try `sudo ufw allow dhclient` and `sudo ufw allow dnsmasq` bot both had `ERROR: Could not find a profile matching` error.
Could you please help me how to allow ap-hotspot?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell

**dnsmasq** uses port 53 tcp/udp, as well as port 67/udp

**dhclient** by default uses port 68/udp

So a generic way to get this setup would be

```
 sudo ufw allow to any port 53
 sudo ufw allow to any port 67 proto udp

 sudo ufw allow to any port 68 proto udp
```

Or if you want to just open these ports for a particular IP address (not sure if you get a static address)

```
 sudo ufw allow from xxx.xxx.x.xx to any port 53
 sudo ufw allow from xxx.xxx.x.xx to any port 67 proto udp

 sudo ufw allow from xxx.xxx.x.xx to any port 68 proto udp
```

You can also add the entries to /etc/services and then ufw will understand when you try

```
 sudo ufw allow dnsmasq
 sudo ufw allow dhclient
```

To do so just edit

```
 sudo nano /etc/services
```

Take a look at the file and it pretty straight forward, but basically you will add

```
 dnsmasq 53/tcp
 dnsmasq 53/udp
 dnsmasq 67/udp

 dhclient 68/udp
```

And then

```
 sudo ufw allow dnsmasq 
 sudo ufw allow dhclient
```

Should work.

Comment: Thanks, my problem solved by `sudo ufw allow bootps` but I can' allow particular ip.

Comment: I was not familiar with that. Learn something new everyday